# Suggestions for free/cheap asset/patch management software (Adobe, Java, etc)

Tags: java, wsus, patch-management, adobe

I am using WSUS for Microsoft patching but would like something that will inventory and patch Adobe, Java, Firefox, Quicktime, etc.

I have used Lumension in the past and it was OK but it is too expensive. I have used Kaseya and don't like it. Shavlik is also too expensive. ECORA's website is difficult to navigate and I am not interested in starting a trial simply based off that.

I downloaded a trial of GFI LANguard which looked nice but it is a standalone .NET application with no web or remote console and crashed throwing .NET errors.

With that said, can anyone suggest me a reasonably priced/free patch management application that will do 3rd party applications, and maybe work with WSUS? A remote client or web interface would be nice also, I also have off-site (VPN) or dis-joined systems.

Comment: Haven't tried it out, but Desktop Central 7 is free up to 25 workstations: http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/index.html

Answer (score 4):

[image]
**WPKG**  
**http://wpkg.org**

"W-package" (GUI and Command line) is an automated software deployment, upgrade and removal tool for Windows.

- WPKG is **[open source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wpkg/)** software.
- It can be used to push/pull software packages, such as Service Packs, hotfixes, or program installations
  from a central server to a number of workstations.
- It can run as a service to install software in the background (silent install), without user interaction.
- It can install MSI, InstallShield, PackagefortheWeb, Inno Setup, Nullsoft, other software installers or .exe packages, .bat and .cmd scripts and similar: no more repackaging to perform software installation.

Here's a **[list of software](http://wpkg.org/Category:Silent_Installers)** that have already available silent installs, upgrades, and uninstalls configurations **(*yes, Adobe flash/reader, Java, Firefox, Quicktime are included here*)**.  You can write your own too, and contribute to the community.

It doesn't include a full "software-push" feature, but we solved this by using **[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)** to run it on all our client/hosts, from a remote computer.

You can use the **[wpkgCreateReport tool](http://wpkg.org/User_contributed_software#wpkgCreateReport)** to generate a report showing which packages are installed on which computers.

*check out the other user contributed software/tools, might come in useful*

---

## LUP

**http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net**

Another solution could be using software called **[Local Update Publisher](http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net/)**.  It allows you to **publish 3rd party software updates through your WSUS server**.  It seems to use WSUS API feature called **"Local Publishing"**.  I haven't used it though, here's what claims to do:

- Publish applications to a domain or workgroup.
- Create rules to define install behavior.
- Monitor progress of installations.
- Use WSUS groups for approvals.
- Utilize existing WSUS architecture. Support multiple parent and child servers.
- Import and export standard update catalogs.

Comment: This is the very reason I wrote Local Update Publishe. The best place to start is http://www.localupdatepublisher.com.

Answer (score 1):

We've started using PDQDeploy, which is free and has worked very well so far (mostly Adobe Flash/Acrobat/Reader updates). Their support is also pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WSUS to deploy all sorts of updates...step by step guide to doing it with Java updates is [here](http://itguru82-sccm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-updates-using-wsussccm.html).

Also stuff on there for doing it with Adobe updates..

Answer (score 0):

Look at [GFI's RemoteManagement](http://www.gfi.com/it-managed-services-software). It's cheap. It works. It's a hosted web-based console. It uses LANguard for patching, so everything you liked without the errors you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com/).  They don't support arbitrary apps, but they do have a curated collection that includes pretty much every high-quality free program you've ever heard of.